# SQL Query for calculating total without considering repeated rows

Tags: sql

I have a table in which i need to calculate total amount.But there are some rows which are getting repeated and i need to avoid those rows.

eg

```
Column1        Column2
   1              10
   2              20
   3              30
   1              10
   2              20
   3              30
```

The problem is i do not know how many times will the values be repeated.

How is it possible?

Comment: In reality, all the column values are getting repeat? or some specified columns values only?

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

- Use `distinct` clause in the inner query to avoid duplicate value
- and then subquery to get total of column2

Like below -

```
    select sum(column2) as totalamount
    from
    (
    select distinct column1, column2
    from tablename
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT
    s.column1,
    sum(s.column2)
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            INNER.column1,
            INNER.coulmn2
        FROM <table> INNER
    ) s
GROUP BY s.column1;
```

This subquery should help you..

Answer (score 0):

This would do

```
Select column1,avg(column2)
from tablename
group by column1
```